# Reason that Java casts to long instead of using the varargs paramter with the correct type?

Tags: java, casting

I have a method with parameters `(byte... a)` and have it overloaded with `(long a, long b)`. Calling the method with two bytes casts it them to `long` rather than using the provided `(byte... a)` method with the correct type. I would expect it to use the method with the correct type rather than casting it. My question is what make Java choose `long` over `byte` for this ambiguous case?

```java
public static void  main(String[] args) {

        byte b = 3;
        foo(b);
        foo(b,b);
        foo(b,b,b);     
    }
    static void foo(byte... a) {

        for(byte elem:a) {
            System.out.print(elem);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    static void foo(long a, long b) {
        System.out.println("Java casts these as longs");
    }
```

The output of this is

```
3
Java casts these as longs
333
```

Comment: yes because you don't have `foo` method that accepts `1` and `3` arguments

Comment: varargs have the lowest execution priority. It should also be understood that unboxing is less priority than expanding to a wider primitive type.